# How can I arrange collectionView cells one under another like a stack of cards in swift

Tags: swift, collectionview

I'm trying implement some what same as in-shorts news app UI. I need to arrange collectionView cells to swipe up to see next but cell should be in a stacked order.Means one over another.I'm adding a screen shot to get more clarity.I tried many ways ,but non of them worked for me. I'm a beginner only.I tried to set zIndex and all.But I'm not getting my target[image].Please help me or suggest me a library if any one know one.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep cell size equal to your collectionView width and height as much you want 
   using sizeForItemAt delegate
2. Keep collectionView scroll direction property to Vertical

Comment: No,thats simple collectionView right? I want to make a deck of card style.. once card over another with some animations to swipe up to see card under it.

Comment: Check whether this library helps you.... https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView